# Is claiming this refund safe?

Tags: mist

Can anyone tell me if it's safe to follow [these instructions](https://medium.com/@VuePay/how-to-claim-your-eth-investment-back-after-vuepay-ico-has-ended-faee35fee9c4) to claim a refund?

I do not have any [significant] Ether on the address I need to claim to but I do have a few tokens that have some value.  Is this totally safe to do?

Also, can anybody tell me how to do it with MEW instead of Mist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That instruction only work for VuePayToken. And you will need some ether to pay for the "claim refund" transaction.

To interact with a contract from MyEtherWallet first obtain the contract ABI from Etherscan. Follow the medium artivle, ie search for VuePayToken:

- From MyEtherWallet select the "Contracts" menu
- In "Contract Address" put the contract address
- In "ABI / JSON interface" paste the "Contract ABI" from Etherscan
- Press "Access" button

A new section "Read / Write contract" will appear with the available functions. Functions that require some extra parameters will show a form, and those that modify the contract will require access to your wallet.

Comment: I understand it's for VuePay.  Is it totally safe to do though?  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Sorry but I have no VuePay tokens and didn't try a refund, but the code appears to be correct.